# Expansion Card in flutter. Children overflowing

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I try to fit my Cloum child of the expantion Card into his expanded Container. It always overflow his Card perent.

I tried a few things like putting the container in a FittedBox but nothing is working. So my goal is to make the column alway fitting in the expanded part of the card, or that the Card expand more if there are to many children in the Column. Can anybuddy tell me this magic trick? Thanks a lot !
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msgQ3.jpg)

```
ExpansionCard(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  child: Text('1000'),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                ),
                borderRadius: 20,
                background: Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/unnamed.jpg",
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                title: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("Freefly Sprung mit Carlo ",
                          style: jumpCardHeaderStyle),
                      Text(
                        DateFormat.yMMMd().format(DateTime.now()),
                        style: jumpCardDateStyle,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                children: <Widget>[
                  FittedBox(
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 7),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text("Exit Alt. : 4000m", style: kJumpTextStyle),
                            Divider(),
                            Text("Dpl. Alt. 1000m", style: kJumpTextStyle),
                            Divider(),
                            Text("Time FF 42sec", style: kJumpTextStyle),
                            Text("AVG.Speed T 127MPH", style: kJumpTextStyle),
                            Text("AVG.Speed T 127MPH", style: kJumpTextStyle),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
```

Comment: Show the design your are trying to acheive

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a card that has a Wrap object as a child? This should allow you to contain everything you need

```
Card(
 child: Wrap(
    children: []
))
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. unfortunately the is still overflowing the card backround. I need to now how i can tell the expantion Card to expand more when the content of his child is larger.